# How to use logging NullHandler in python 2.6

Tags: logging, python-2.6

Most of my code at this point has been designed to run on python 2.76. So the library I wrote uses the following code so that any consumers of my libraries can have debug logging coming from the library:

So in each library file I have this:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

This way if a client script using my library instantiates a logger object, the library will have log output as well.

However, I now need to tweak this library so it runs on python 2.6 and it's complaining about this bit of code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./LCMTool.py", line 36, in <module>
    from lcm_zfssa  import *
  File "/devel/v2/lcm_zfssa.py", line 20, in <module>
    log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NullHandler'
```

Is there a way to tweak this so that this will work with python 2.6?

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how distributed your issue is, the solution from the [Python Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/#logging-in-a-library) (and ultimately from [requests source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)) might work:  try importing NullHandler and in the `except ImportError` clause, define the class like so:

```
# Set default logging handler to avoid "No handler found" warnings.
import logging
try:  # Python 2.7+
    from logging import NullHandler
except ImportError:
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record):
            pass

logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(NullHandler())
```

Though if using the logging namespace, you'll then want to insert the class:

```
# in the except clause, after the class def:
logging.NullHandler = NullHandler
```

Comment: I have seen the `NullHadler` on the python how to guide. What is the purpose of `NullHandler`?

Comment: I'd recommend checking the official Python docs.  I don't know I could add anything add anything that's not already said there.

Comment: @alpha_989 Take a look at this: https://realpython.com/python-logging-source-code/#library-vs-application-logging-what-is-nullhandler

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommended solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6

import os
import logging
modlog = logging.getLogger(__name__)
modlog.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(os.devnull))

# ... remaining code
```